# Fechamento da lotofácil com erro na impressão PHP

Tags: php, html, html5, php-7

Galera, eu preciso da ajuda de vocês se possível... Eu criei um sistema de geração de jogos na lotofácil, baseado em um outro sistema...
Bom o meu sistema não é muito complexo... o usuário escolhe 5 dezenas/números para excluir de seus jogos, e o gerador gera 356 combinações diferentes...

Até ai tudo bem, eu consegui fazer o código que gera todas as combinações possíveis na sequencia de 20 números, fazendo combinações de 15... e mostro para o usuário 356 das mais de 15 mil combinações...

O meu sistema compara os números com o último jogo, e diz quantos pontos e reais(R$) o usuário teria feito com aqueles jogos...

O problema é que na outro sistema, as combinações que se "geram" quando se exclui os 5 números, sempre dá pelo menos 1 resultado de 14 acertos e o meu não, pois se faz a exclusão de 5 números que não saíram no último concurso...

```
//Primeiras Impressões do Sistema Excluindo as Dezenas: 02  03  05  08 09

1   4   4   6   7   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  18  22  23
1   4   4   6   7   10  11  12  13  14  15  18  19  20  21
1   4   4   6   7   10  11  12  13  14  16  18  19  22  24
1   4   4   6   7   10  11  12  13  14  17  18  19  23  24
1   4   4   6   7   10  11  12  13  15  16  17  18  22  23
1   4   4   6   7   10  11  12  13  15  16  18  20  21  22
1   4   4   6   7   10  11  12  13  15  16  20  21  22  23
1   4   4   6   7   10  11  12  13  15  17  18  20  21  24
1   4   4   6   7   10  11  12  13  16  17  20  22  23  24
1   4   4   6   7   10  11  12  13  16  18  21  22  23  24
1   4   4   6   7   10  11  12  14  15  16  17  19  20  23
```

Essas são as primeiras 11, mas já dá para notar que são bem diferentes das minhas que são:

```
//Primeiras Impressões do Meu Sistema Excluindo as Dezenas: $exclusao=["02","03","05","08","09"];

Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 04 [2] => 06 [3] => 07 [4] => 10 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 14 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 19 [14] => 20 )
Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 04 [2] => 06 [3] => 07 [4] => 10 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 14 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 19 [14] => 21 )
Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 04 [2] => 06 [3] => 07 [4] => 10 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 14 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 19 [14] => 22 )
Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 04 [2] => 06 [3] => 07 [4] => 10 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 14 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 19 [14] => 23 )
Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 04 [2] => 06 [3] => 07 [4] => 10 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 14 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 19 [14] => 24 )
Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 04 [2] => 06 [3] => 07 [4] => 10 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 14 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 19 [14] => 25 ) 
Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 04 [2] => 06 [3] => 07 [4] => 10 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 14 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 20 [14] => 21 )
Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 04 [2] => 06 [3] => 07 [4] => 10 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 14 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 20 [14] => 22 )
Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 04 [2] => 06 [3] => 07 [4] => 10 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 14 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 20 [14] => 23 )
Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 04 [2] => 06 [3] => 07 [4] => 10 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 14 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 20 [14] => 24 )
Array ( [0] => 01 [1] => 04 [2] => 06 [3] => 07 [4] => 10 [5] => 11 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 14 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 20 [14] => 25 )
```

Meu código de geração é esse:

```
$dezenas =array_diff($numeros,$exclusao);
sort($dezenas);
function combinacoesDe($k, $xs){
    if ($k === 0)
        return array(array());
    if (count($xs) === 0)
        return array();
    $x = $xs[0];

    $xs1 = array_slice($xs,1,count($xs)-1);

    $res1 = combinacoesDe($k-1,$xs1);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($res1); $i++) {
        array_splice($res1[$i], 0, 0, $x);
    }
    $res2 = combinacoesDe($k,$xs1);

    return array_merge($res1, $res2);
}
$resultado = combinacoesDe(15,$dezenas);
```

E o de impressão e comparação é esse:

```html
  <?php $numaposta=1;
  for($z =1  ; $z <= 356 ; $z++) {  
echo "<div class='mostra-aposta'>";
echo"<h4 style=''>Aposta $numaposta </h4>";
$numaposta=$numaposta+1;
for($x = 1 ; $x <= 25 ; $x++) { ?>
<span <?php if(in_array($x,$resultado[$z])!== FALSE){echo"class='ok'";}elseif(in_array($x,$exclusao)!== FALSE){echo"class='ok2'";}else{} ?>><?php echo"$x"; ?></span>
<?php
}
$quantos = array_intersect($dezenasr, $resultado[$z]);
$premio = count($quantos);
 if($premio===15){
 array_push($a15, $z);
}elseif($premio===14){
 array_push($a14, $z);
}elseif($premio===13){
 array_push($a13, $z);
}elseif($premio===12){
 array_push($a12, $z);
}elseif($premio===11){
 array_push($a11, $z);
}
echo "</div>";
}
$puxarht=ob_get_contents();
$htb64=base64_encode($puxarht);
ob_end_flush();
$n15=count($a15);
$n14=count($a14);
$n13=count($a13);
$n12=count($a12);
$n11=count($a11);
$premio15=$quinze -> valor_pago * $n15;
$premio14=$quatorze -> valor_pago * $n14;
$premio14=str_replace(".","",$premio14);
$premio13=$treze -> valor_pago * $n13;
$premio12=$doze -> valor_pago * $n12;
$premio11=$onze -> valor_pago * $n11;
$premiototal=$premio15+$premio14+$premio13+$premio12+$premio11;
$totaldeacertos=$n11+$n12+$n13+$n14+$n15;
?>
```

Eu já fiz a comparação e todos os as sequências geradas no sistema deles, tá entre as minhas mais de 15 mil combinações... o problema é que bem distantes umas das outras... Agradeceria se pudessem me ajudar com isso, Obrigado!

Comment: Não deu pra entender o que você quer. Eu também desenvolvi algo semelhante http://kithomepage.com/arrayCombLotofacil.php

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz algo parecido, eu gero mais combinações que necessário, alem disso continuo gerando combinações caso nao acerta 14 pontos, depois eu excluo do array as combinações que dão menos pontos.

estou copiando o código aqui para vc...

```
public function apostasr5_pre(Request $request){

    $numeros = $request->input('param2');
    $concurso_id = $request->input('param3');
    $concurso = resultados::where('id',$concurso_id)->first();
    $concurso_valor = unserialize($concurso->valores);
   
    $id = $this->GERA_R5($numeros);
 
    $g = saved_games::where('id',$id)->first();
    $sequencias = unserialize($g->games);
  
    $acerta11=0; $acerta12=0;  $acerta13=0; $acerta14=0; $acerta15=0;
    foreach($sequencias as $jogos){
        $cont=0;
        
        foreach($jogos as $jogo){
            if(in_array($jogo, $concurso_valor)){ 
                $cont++; 
            
            }
           
        }//endforeach1    
       
            if($cont == 11){ $acerta11++; } 
            if($cont == 12){ $acerta12++; } 
            if($cont == 13){ $acerta13++; } 
            if($cont == 14){ $acerta14++; } 
            if($cont == 15){ $acerta15++; }
         
    }//endforeach2
    $arr=[];

    array_push($arr ,['11',$acerta11, ($acerta11 * $concurso->acertos11) ]);
    array_push($arr ,['12',$acerta12, ($acerta12 * $concurso->acertos12) ]);
    array_push($arr ,['13',$acerta13, ($acerta13 * $concurso->acertos13) ]);
    array_push($arr ,['14',$acerta14, ($acerta14 * $concurso->acertos14) ]);
    array_push($arr ,['15',$acerta15, ($acerta15 * $concurso->acertos15) ]);

    return view('resultados.conferencia')->with('dados',$arr);

}

public function GERA_R5($numeros){

    //saved_games::truncate();

    $id_game = 'Lotofácil-Erre-5';
    $date_show = '2020-04-02 00:00:00';
    
    $numeros_arr = array_map('intval',explode("-",$numeros));
    sort($numeros_arr);
   
    $resultados = resultados::orderby('concurso','desc')->take(370)->get();
    $data = $resultados[0]->data;
    $g = saved_games::where('sequence',serialize($numeros_arr))
                    ->where('id_game',$id_game)->where('created_at','>=',$data)
                    ->first();
     if(!$g){

        $g = new saved_games;
        $g->id_game = $id_game;
        $g->sequence = serialize($numeros_arr);
        $g->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $g->date_show = $date_show;
        
      
        $mestre= [];
        $out = [];

        foreach($resultados as $resultado){
        

        $acertos = 0;
        $out = [];
        $max = 14;
        $valor_resultado = unserialize($resultado->valores);
     
        $errei = 0;
        $errei = $this->conta($valor_resultado,$numeros_arr);

  

        if($errei == 0){ $max=14; }
        else { $max = 1; }    

            while($acertos < $max){
                $dezena = $this->gera_dezena_r5($numeros_arr);
                $acertos = $this->conta($valor_resultado, $dezena);
            }

        
            array_push($mestre,$dezena); 
        } //for mestre

        $mestre = array_unique($mestre, SORT_REGULAR);
        array_splice($mestre, 356);

        $g->games = serialize($mestre);
        $g->save();

           
     }

     return $g->id;   

}

public function gera_dezena_r5($numeros){
            $in = $numeros;
            $out = [];
                for ($i=0; $i < 15; $i++) {
                    do {
                        $rand = rand(1, 25);
                    } while(in_array($rand, $in));
                    array_push($in, $rand);
                    array_push($out, $rand);
                } //for completa
            sort($out);
return  $out;
}




public function conta($r,$d){
    $cont=0;
    foreach($r as $valor){
      if(in_array($valor,$d)){
          $cont +=1;
      }
    }
    return $cont;
}
```